# MySQL select dates between with date functions and min max

Tags: mysql, date, between

Why does this return '2015-01-19'?:

```
SELECT date
FROM hours 
HAVING date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(max(date), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(max(date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

when this returns '2015-01-20' and '2015-01-19'?:

```
SELECT date 
FROM hours 
HAVING date BETWEEN '2015-01-18' AND '2015-01-21'
```

max date is '2015-01-20' and there are records on both '2015-01-20' and '2015-01-19'. date is a date field.

Comment: Can you explain some more? in which scenario? what data in `hours`?

Comment: working hours and other user/employee related data by work date. can contain multiple records for a spesific date for one user/employee. i actually want to return * for the date interval and not just the date. when using the latter query phpmyadmin actually add ORDER BY 'time' DESC to the end of the query. don't know why...

Comment: You forgot to put `GROUP BY date` before `HAVING date`..

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that `date_sub` returns a full time stamp e.g. '2008-11-11 13:23:44.657' see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp for more details.

You'll want to use the `extract` method or `date_format` ( `DATE_FORMAT(date_time_var, '%Y-%m-%d')` ) to get just the day, month and year as used in your between statement.

Comment: "The return value depends on the arguments" [ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add ] Here, result is only a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example contains aggregate functions. HAVING typically requires a GROUP BY, because it's a means to filter groups. So putting `GROUP BY date` before `HAVING date` will get you both the 19th and 20th (for your first SQL statement).

Comment: Tested, and failed:  ``GROUP BY date`` groups rows by ``date`` value, hence the ``MAX(date)`` is that ``date`` value and ``HAVING`` clause is ``true`` for each grouped rowset. Note that ``HAVING`` does not require ``GROUP BY``.

Answer (score 0):

That's `HAVING` behaviour.

`HAVING` will *group* results in your first query because there is a grouping function `MAX` in `HAVING` clause. *All* returned rows will be grouped in *one* row-group because there is no `GROUP BY` instruction. Therefore, you only get one result. `date` value of this group can be *any* of the grouped rows.

`HAVING` will do no group in second query because there is no grouping function in `HAVING` clause, nor `GROUP BY` instruction.

Adding a `GROUP BY date` as suggested will group rows that have the same `date`; hence `MAX` will only return that `date` value instead of `MAX` of all dates. So, you will retrieve all rows because `MAX(date)`==`date` in all grouped rows.

---

```
SELECT `date`, GROUP_CONCAT(`date`), (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM `hours`) AS `md`
FROM `hours`
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING `date`
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(md, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(md, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

You might also use

```
SELECT `hours`.`date`, `md`.`d`
FROM `hours`, (SELECT MAX(`date`) AS `d` FROM `hours`) AS `md`
WHERE `hours`.`date`
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(`md`.`d`, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(`md`.`d`, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Not sure which one is the fastest...

Comment: Thanks guys! Works like charm now that I put GROUP BY before HAVING. A rookie mistake I know...